# How can I change which python I use in R notebook?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to use my anaconda installation in R notebook ( `/anaconda/bin/python`).

As it stands, R is using my MacBook's stock python installation (python 2.7).

How can I point R towards using my anaconda installation in R notebooks instead?

EDIT:  Just found out about `engine.path`.  Any way to set `/anaconda/bin/python` as the default python installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on how you setup your `PATH` variable in your R session. I also use a Mac & anaconda, if I do `which python` I get

```
/Users/<my user name>/tools/anaconda/bin/python
```

but this is because in my `.bash_profile` I set (not sure if `conda` did it when it was installed, or I did it myself),

```
export PATH="/Users/<my user name>/tools/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

However if I do `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in my R session I get,

```
[1] "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"
```

With that, I point to python in `/usr/bin`. However I do this,

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("/Users/<my user name>/tools/anaconda/bin",
           Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

I start pointing to the conda version.

Comment: Hi @DemetriP, happy that I could help! It would appreciate if you accept the answer. Thanks!